# Running large jobs with low startup time and autoscaling for bursts of traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-batch

For a website I’m developing on AWS, a user can submit a large job (ex. select a large number of items and ask to update them all in some way). We don’t want to limit the size of the job these users are submitting so this job can can in theory run for a very long period of time and require a large amount of memory (this rules out AWS Lambda as a compute engine option). We want jobs to be as independent from one another as possible so we chose to run each job in its own container in Amazon ECS. What we currently do when a user submits a job request is send a message with a job id/reference to an SQS queue, have AWS lambda poll that queue and upon receiving a message, lambda starts an ECS task (SQS -> Lambda -> ECS). This has the problem that a new ECS task is started with each request, so a new container must be booted up which can take minutes. This latency is directly visible to the user and is particularly unacceptable if the users job is not even particularly large yet they still wait for minutes for the container to boot up. Additionally, the cost of constantly running container or two would not be too problematic.

I've been toying with some ideas for updating this flow.

**Attempt 1:**
In this updated flow we'd create an ECS task that looks like the following:

```
message = null; 
while (message == null) { 
    message = pollForMessages(); 
} 
processMessage(message); 
// task finishes, and container can be brought down
```

We remove the lambda from the flow and just have SQS -> ECS rather than SQS -> Lambda -> ECS. In this case, there would be no cold start assuming a container is up spinning for messages. We could set the minimum number of tasks we want running to be a number > 0 to ensure all messages are processed at some point. However this suffers from the problem that it would not auto-scale as the number of messages in the queue increases. So something needs to spawn more containers when traffic increases.

**Attempt 2:**
In this updated flow we'd create an ECS task that looks like the following:

```
message = null; 
while (message == null) { 
    message = pollForMessages(); 
} 
If (number of running tasks < number of messages in queue) {
    spawnMoreContainers();
}
processMessage(message); 
// task finishes, and container can be brought down
```

This comes with the issue that we could end up over provisioning containers if multiple containers see that there are more messages in the queue than tasks running. Since these tasks run forever until a message is processed this could result in a large unnecessary cost. It could also under provision containers - if the task sees that number of running tasks >= number of messages, but these running tasks are already busy processing messages, these tasks will not end up taking one of these messages out of the queue and we may end up with messages that have to wait a very long time to be processed.

**Attempt 3:**

```
message = null; 
while (message == null) { 
    message = pollForMessages(); 
    If (# of containers > min provisioned && this particular container has been running longer than some timeout) {
        // finish this task so this container can be brought down
        return;
    }
} 
If (number of running tasks < number of messages in queue) {
    spawnMoreContainers();
}
processMessage(message); 
// task finishes, and container can be brought down
```

While this may save us some cost compared to Attempt 2 so over provisioning wouldn’t be so much of an issue, there is still the possibility that we could under provision containers, in which case certain job requests would need to wait for potentially long periods of time before being processed.

**Attempt 4:**
We can introduce locking (ex. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/) to mitigate some of the race conditions, however we'll always have the issue that a task running does not necessarily mean a task that is available to pick up messages and Fargate gives us no way of distinguishing between these, which makes it difficult to determine how many containers to provision (ex. we see there are 5 running containers and 5 messages, but we don't know whether to provision more containers or not because we don't know if those containers are already processing a message or if they're waiting). Alternatively we could introduce some mechanism, either an external orchestrator or some logic within the containers and some data store, to manage the state of these containers.

Essentially to deal with each of these problems, the architecture becomes more and more complex and implementation would be difficult and error prone.
It also seems to me like these solutions are reinventing the wheel, and I feel there must be some service out there that has solved this problem already, but I can’t seem to find it.

The suggestions I’ve seen to deal with this are:

- **Maybe AWS batch is more suited for this use case** - Indeed, AWS batch might be the more recommended approach for a workload like this but, we don’t remove any of the cold start problem by switching. AWS batch would still create a new container with each job.
- **Run the ECS tasks on EC2 rather than Fargate, then cache the container image on the host** -  With this, we’d be managing our own infrastructure  and ideally we’d like this to be serverless.
- **Have an alarm on the number of messages in the queue and have this alarm trigger a lambda that then boots up more containers** - alarms on the /AWS log group have a minimum period of 1 minute. This means the alarm would not be triggered until a minute after we’d received more requests than our provisioned containers can handle. Additionally we'd have to set up many alarms to scale at different numbers of messages.

I’m wondering if anyone is aware of potential services/frameworks that could make doing this more feasible? Or if anyone has suggestions on alternative architectures?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a bit slower response time to the bursts, you may create an autoscaling group (I assume there is something similar for ECS). This group can be governed by a custom metric, e. g. queue length divided by the number of workers. A detailed guide is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html

In any case, I'd decouple the scaling decision from the worker code, because there is a varying number of workers that you would need to synchronize. It's much easier to have one overseer that controls how many workers there should be. Because the overseer is not on the critical path to task processing, you don't need to care that much about its uptime. It's OK if it takes a few minutes before it recovers after a failure - the workers are still there, processing at least at some capacity.